# Motrar datos de un modelo con una relacion con otro

Tags: python, django

Quisiera hacer lo siguiente:

Tengo estos modelo con ciertos datos:

```
class Computadora(models.Model):
    inv = models.CharField('Inventario de PC', max_length=100, unique=True)
    monitor = models.ForeignKey(Monitor, verbose_name='Monitor', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area, verbose_name='Area', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

```
class Monitor(models.Model):
    #fecha =models.DateField('Fecha del registro')
    inv = models.CharField('Numero de Inventario', max_length=100)
    tamano = models.CharField('Tamano del Monitor', max_length=100)
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area, verbose_name='Area de Ubicacion', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fabricante = models.ForeignKey(Fabricante, verbose_name='Fabricante', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    serial = models.CharField('Numero de Serie del Monitor', max_length=100, unique=True)
```

Lo que quiero es lo siguiente:

hacer una consulta al modelo computadora pero quisiera que me muestre los datos del modelo Monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Ya resolví como algo tan sencillo lo tenia a mano pero me faltaba plantearlo correctamente en el template

Esta es la vista como lo resolví.

```
def list_pc(request,pk):
    pc = Pc.objects.select_related().filter(pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'prueba.html', {'pc':pc})
```

Este es como lo plantee en el Template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Fecha</th>
            <th>Sello</th>
            <th>Inventario</th>
            <th>Marca Disco</th>
            <th>Marca Serial del Disco</th>
            <th>Marca Modelo del Disco</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for pc in pc %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ pc.fecha }}</td>
                <td>{{ pc.sello }}</td>
                <td>{{ pc.inv }}</td>
                <td>{{ pc.discos.marca }}</td>
                <td>{{ pc.discos.serial }}</td>
                <td>{{ pc.discos.modelo }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Espero que esto ayude a futuras preguntas similares